# My cordova app is not working in M1 a1 mobile

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Our android cordova app is working file in all phones but in Mi A1 mobiles it's not working properly , any idea ?

Comment: try to debug with ** Mi A1** mobile using `chrome://inspect/#devices` and check may be some error or warring

Comment: I don't have that phone , is there any online tool or simulator ?

Comment: no there is no `online tool or simulator`. because it's device specific issue so you need to check on that device.

Comment: ok let me try with some device

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"? What is happening exactly? What debug tools are you using? Try Visual Studio 2017 to run and debug on device in real time, it works with any Android > 5.0. Without debug data no one can help you.

Comment: The problem could be Android 8 , try on this operating sistem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is below., This may help someone.

In Mi A1 mobile the browser name will show us OPR but sencha not having the name in list so change the below code in touch\src\env\Browser.js line No : 231

Old Code

```
    if (userAgent.match(/OPR/)) {
        browserMatch = userAgent.match(/OPR\/(\d+.\d+)/);
        browserName = 'Opera';           
        browserVersion = new Ext.Version(browserMatch[1]);
    }
```

New Code

```
browserMatch = userAgent.match(/OPR\/(\d+.\d+)/);
    if (userAgent.match(/OPR/)) {
          if (browserMatch) {
        browserName = 'Opera';           
        browserVersion = new Ext.Version(browserMatch[1]);
        }
    }
```